# Navigating hyperlink only restrict to mouse click?

Tags: c#, mouseevent, hook, keyboard-hook

I just want to restrict a hyperlink firing via only mouse click. None of the keyboard movements should not fire the hyperlink. I want to achieve this on C#

Comment: A hyperlink, where? WebBrowser? WebView?

Comment: hyperlink in word window.i am triggering this hyperlink through Applicationwindowselectionchange event

Comment: Thanks for sharing. What exactly is your question? Have you tried anything?

Comment: public static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application App
    {
      get;
       set;
    }  
    App.WindowSelectionChange += new ApplicationEvents4_WindowSelectionChangeEventHandler(ApplicationWindowSelectionChange);                                           

    ApplicationWindowSelectionChange(Selection selection){
    if (OfficeWindow != null )
    {
        OfficeWindow.Hyperlink(link, linkType, OfficeWindow.Context);
    }

Comment: Pranav, please edit your post instead of adding comments. Code in comment is not readable at all.